# Loading a class within a class

Tags: templates, document-classes, documentclass-writing, article

I'm trying to develop a set of custom classes. They are all very similar, but each do slightly different things (a custom `letter`, `article` and `report` for example. Since they share things in common, I thought that to cut down on repeated code, I could have a 'base' class, which would define everything they have in common, and then I would have the specific classes, with their individual code.

That base class is called `frigaard-base.cls`, and then I have a class for essays, called `frigaard-essay.cls`. The structure is that `frigaard-base` loads the default `article` and then `frigaard-essay` loads `frigaard-base`. However in a document when I load `frigaard-essay.cls`, I get the following error:

```
File `frigaard-base.cls' not found. \LoadClass{frigaard-base}
```

Normally though, it should be found since `frigaard-base` and `frigaard-essay` are in the same folder, and here is their declarations:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2011/06/27]
\ProvidesClass{frigaard-base}[2013/07/24]
\LoadClass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
```

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2011/06/27]
\ProvidesClass{frigaard-essay}[2013/07/24]
\LoadClass{frigaard-base}[2013/07/24]
```

What is happening here? Should I not be using `\LoadClass` twice within the same hierarchy and change `frigaard-base` into some other file type, such as a `.def` (if this is the case, please explain how).

**More Info**

It has been worked out that when `frigaard-base.cls`, `frigaard-essay.cls`, and a test document are in the same folder, then it works fine, but when say the test document is in a folder, `frigaard-essay.cls` is in a subfolder, and `frigaard-base.cls` is in a subfolder of that, it gives the same error.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you. ps. You can separate two consecutive code blocks with an HTML comment `<!-->` like I did in my edit …

Comment: This scenario works fine for me with both `frigaard-<name>.cls` files in the same folder as my test file.

Comment: @cgnieder Just checked, and it does for me too. However it does not work when the two classes are in a seperate file. Is that the same for you?

Comment: Do you mean separate _folder_? That would need to be a folder that TeX can find (supposedly somewhere in your local TeX tree) and you'd need to make the files known to TeX by running `texhash` or `mktexlsr` (assuming TeX Live here, I know nothing about MiKTeX)

Comment: @cgnieder Yeah sorry, I meant folder. My current folder structure looks a like this X:\latex\classes for where `frigaard-base` and `frigaard-essay`, and x:\latex\documents for where my test file is. I'm using MiKTeX, but this structure has previously worked in the past, which is why I put the problem down to using `\LoadClass` to load a class (which has already loaded `article` into another class.

Comment: Have you seen the question [How can I manually install a package on MiKTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/how-can-i-manually-install-a-package-on-miktex-windows)? It's the same for classes.